# Is there a way to change what the .operator "string" will be conditionally

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

This is going to sound very weird but it will make the code for this app very compact.

Is there a way to call a .operator conditionally. Here is an example

say I have a class with three values that I can do a . on.

```
class A {
int intOne;
int intTwo;
int intThree;
}
```

to get the intOne in class A you can do A.intOne right....

but what if you you wanted the string at the right of the . to conditionally be there.

A."conditionalvariable"

so if a user clicks a button say button A then the conditional variable will be A.intOne.
and if the user clicks button b then the value of "conditionalvariable" will be intTwo and therefore you will be getting the data.

please assume that I am not stupid, and I am needing this exact thing for a specific use case. If you post an answer that is not this exact solution it will not be accepted.

example:

```
var a;
switch (name) {
case "intOne":
  a = A.intOne;
  break;
... 
}
```

//this is not an acceptable answer
I realize that this would be an "answer" to this question, but it actually isn't I need the exact thing stated because I am using streams.

here is that use case I was talking about. I could explain away all day as to why I need it this way, but either way this either does exist or doesn't so a simple no this doesn't exist is an acceptable answer.

```
return StreamProvider.value(
      value: classDataNotif.homework,
)
```

based on what is clicked before this widget the "homework" will need to change to "notes", or "tests".

You cannot do a switch above this because it will be calling the stream to early and cause the widget to crash. doing a switch inside the widget and copying code over would defeat the purpose. in order to make the code as compact and as easy to write as possible i need the string at the right of the . operator to change.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. Now I'm not sure if this is possible or not but this reminds me a lot of java reflections where you have operators to access the fields, so maybe take a look at [this](https://itnext.io/understanding-reflection-and-annotations-in-dart-f1e28efdb064) and see if there's "Reflections" in dart! Hope this helps

Comment: This would only be possible with reflection which is possible with just dart. But it seems you're using flutter so this cannot be done.